# Set the same height of the rectangle with different splits in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I posted the same question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845937/set-the-same-height-of-the-splits-with-tikz). I am not able to get the figure with two nodes the same height (10 cm), when they are rectangles split in different number of parts. It appears when the object is split in more parts the total height, apparently, increases. How to fix this?

The reproducible example and the actual output is on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845937/set-the-same-height-of-the-splits-with-tikz).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows}

\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][#1][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text I}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Cir 1\\67\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cir 2\\33\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=4, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{4.6cm}{Cir 1\\ 46\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3cm}{Met \\30\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.4cm}{Let\\24\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text II}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Part 1\\33\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Part 2\\67\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=5, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30,yellow!15},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cr1 \\ 33\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{2.5cm}{Cr2\\25\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.2cm}{Cr3\\22\%}
            \nodepart{five}\Textbox{2.0cm}{Cr4\\20\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two interesting points I observe: (1) If I redefine `\newcommand\Textbox[2]{\parbox[c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}\rule[-.5\dimexpr#1\relax]{2pt}{#1}}%`, you will see that the vertical extent of the box extends well past the vertical rule (sort of an `\fboxsep` effect); and (2) if I also add `\begin{subfigure}[b]{1cm}
    \rule{1pt}{2.0cm}\rule[2cm]{1pt}{2.2cm}\rule[4.2cm]{1pt}{2.5cm}\rule[6.7cm]{1pt}{3.3cm}
    \end{subfigure}` as a 3rd subfigure, then I see that these rules are larger than the supposedly equivalent rules inside subgiure 2.  Most strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comment to the OP, there seems to be some sort of `\fboxsep` effect going on that I do not know how to fix in `tikz`.  However, I can overcome it by redefining `\Textbox` to subtract off `7.7pt` (or 1.62ex) from its vertical height for each construction.

```
\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-7.7pt][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}
```

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows}

\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-7.7pt][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text I}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Cir 1\\67\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cir 2\\33\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=4, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{4.6cm}{Cir 1\\ 46\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3cm}{Met \\30\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.4cm}{Let\\24\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text II}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Part 1\\33\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Part 2\\67\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=6, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30,yellow!15,
                                   red!15},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cr1 \\ 33\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{1.5cm}{Cr2\\15\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.2cm}{Cr3\\22\%}
            \nodepart{five}\Textbox{1.2cm}{Cr4\\12\%}
            \nodepart{six}\Textbox{1.8cm}{Cr4\\18\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The so called `\fboxsep` effect I make reference to above (where a border of finite size is added to the defined image) can be seen by redefining

```
\renewcommand\Textbox[2]{%
  \parbox[c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}%
  \rule[-.5\dimexpr#1]{2pt}{#1}%
}
```

When this is done, the result looks like the following, clearly showing the box extending well past the vertical extent of the rule:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As manual says (pages 716-171)

> When split vertically, the rectangle split will meet any `minimum width` requirements, but any
>   `minimum height` will be ignored. Conversely when split horizontally, `minimum height` requirements will be met, but any `minimum width` will be ignored. In addition, `inner sep` is applied to every part
>   that is used, so it cannot be speciﬁed independently for a particular part.

You're trying to force a `minimum height` to the whole multipart fixing each part height with `\Textbox` command. This is perfect, but you have forgotten that an `inner sep` is added to each `\Textbox` size before drawing its border.
If both multipart nodes have equal parts, this is not a problem, but as soon as one have tree and the other four, height discrepancies appear.

The best solution could be to force `inner sep=0pt` or `inner ysep=0pt`. But this is not enough, because you also need to consider how many horizontal borders you have and compensate the difference between parallel multipart nodes.
In left example, `Tit A` nodes has three components while `Tit B` has four, while in right examples, divisions are three against five. This means that right boxes will be `\pgflinewidth` and `2\pgflinewidth` higher than left boxes.

You have to decide where you want to adjust this differences. In following code I've shortened the lower right part. I've also used `inner sep=0pt` in all nodes and used `\Textbox` also for titles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows}

\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][#1][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text I}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east,
        inner sep=0pt %<--------------------------
        ]{\Textbox{1cm}{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Cir 1\\67\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cir 2\\33\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=4, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30},
        anchor=north west,
        inner sep=0pt %<--------------------------
        ]{\Textbox{1cm}{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{4.6cm}{Cir 1\\ 46\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3cm}{Met \\30\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.4cm-\pgflinewidth} %<-----
                 {Let\\24\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text II}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east,
        inner sep=0pt %<--------------------------
        ]{\Textbox{1cm}{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Part 1\\33\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Part 2\\67\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=5, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30,yellow!15},
        anchor=north west,
        inner sep=0pt %<--------------------------
        ]{\Textbox{1cm}{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cr1 \\ 33\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{2.5cm}{Cr2\\25\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.2cm}{Cr3\\22\%}
            \nodepart{five}\Textbox{2.0cm-2\pgflinewidth}%<-----
            {Cr4\\20\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]