# Set the same height of the splits with tikz

Tags: floats, tikz-pgf

I am not able to get the figure with the same height (10 cm). When a division is split in more parts the height, apparently increases. How to fix this?

Here is a reproducible example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows}

\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][#1][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text I}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Cir 1\\67\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cir 2\\33\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=4, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{4.6cm}{Cir 1\\ 46\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{3cm}{Met \\30\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.4cm}{Let\\24\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (h1) {\textbf{Text II}};
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3, below of= h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, green!15},
        anchor=north east]{\textbf{Tit A}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Part 1\\33\% } 
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{6.7cm}{Part 2\\67\%} };
        \node[draw,
        align=center,
        text width=2.5cm,
        %minimum height=7cm,
        draw=red!50,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=5, below of=h1,yshift=0.5cm,
        rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!15, green!15,green!30,yellow!15},
        anchor=north west]{\textbf{Tit B}
            \nodepart{two}\Textbox{3.3cm}{Cr1 \\ 33\%}  
            \nodepart{three}\Textbox{2.5cm}{Cr2\\25\%}  
            \nodepart{four}\Textbox{2.2cm}{Cr3\\22\%}
            \nodepart{five}\Textbox{2.0cm}{Cr4\\20\%} };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259040/83280) @Steven B. Segletes proposed to modify the `\Textbox` command, subtracting 7.7pt of each split height.

```
\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-7.7pt][c]{2.3cm}{\centering#2}}
```

Comment: There's [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259243/1952) which explains why these height differences appear and how to solve them.